# bash show all lines per count of a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I am not a bash ninja and I have a file with lines like the below:

```
timestamp1 value1 value2 value3 username host
```

I want to print all the values3 and values2 which will be different everytime where host was the same for lets say X times. I know how to grep per host and awk the columns however I dont know how to set the count for a variable?

So for example - if the host appears 5 times on the file I want to print these 5 lines. But the thing here is that I dont know the host so I need to specify it in a variable and somehow count it?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the input, your attempted code, and the actual and expected output.

Comment: Add here what you already _know_ (as you said). We can help how to continue.

Comment: the example that i provided is ok meaning that the format is exactly like this. What I want to see is all the lines that contain a host which appears more than X (lets say 5 times) in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One-Liner Solution

Assume your file's name was `lst` Here's the oneliner:

```
grep -Ff <(awk '{print $6}' lst | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 == 5 {print $2}') lst
```

**What happens?**

- Extract all hostnames from the file
- For each hostname, count the number of occurences
- Print only the hostnames which appear exactly 5 times
- Grep the file for the filtered out hostnames

**Note:**

- Hostnames must not appear inside the other fields (would lead to false positives).
- The output is ordered as the original file (may not be sorted according to hostname). You can however add a `| sort` to the end of the command.